# vim very slow over SSH connection

Tags: ssh, vim, strace, lag, latency

I have a non-stellar SSH connection to some machine; the echo time is... I don't know, 0.2 seconds or so.

Anyway, when I start vim, say with no input file, I experience a long delay, of about 3 to 4 seconds, which - when I connect over a lower-latency SSH connection (i.e. within the same network segment), I don't experience. This delay is *before* vim has written anything to the terminal, and hence before it can expect me to input anything - so I'm wondering what's causing it to try to communicate over the connection, and what exactly it's communicating.

I used strace -rr, looking for differences of over 0.1 seconds, and noticed a bunch of these lines:

```
     0.284973 recvfrom(3, "\1\0\v\0\0\0\340\1", 8, 0, NULL, NULL) = 8
     0.133300 recvmsg(3, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\1\205\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
     0.138255 recvmsg(3, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\1\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\377\377?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
     0.148123 recvmsg(3, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\1\10\4\0M\1\0\0\37\0\0\0\0\0\0\0001\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 1364
```

(and this repeats itself again and again.)

What's going on with these messages? And - how can I make vim skip these communications attempts and just come up faster?

Comment: While vim is aware of the type of terminal it's using, it doesn't concern itself with the fact that there's network between you and the remote machine on which you run vim.

So, I don't exactly know which socket is behind your file descriptor `3`, but this is probably some service thing that vim tries to talk to; and through some mechanism, that goes wrong when you're connecting over high-latency network.

Comment: you will have to find out what this `3` is; probably from a `socket` call that happens earlier. Also, probably not really related to the fact you're doing this over slow SSH – as vim has no idea of the network, I bet this is a "red herring", unless you forward some services through SSH (say, X forwarding, and vim is actually some alias to a potentially graphical vim frontend?).

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was X11 forwarding. I had X11 forwarding enabled for this connection, and I had also noticed that X11 apps were e-x-t-r-e-m-e-l-y slow and unresponsive, so much so that I don't use any; but the forwarding renamed enabled.

And when I disable it, or even if I made it unnoticeable by executing:

```
unset DISPLAY
```

vim startup becomes very snappy!

I believe vim tries to figure out whether it needs to run in an X window, for some reason; and that file-descriptor-3 communications is it trying to communicate with the X server on a socket it opens.

I've asked a [followup question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/732849/34868) about preventing vim from even trying to do this.

<sub>Thanks goes to @MarcusMuller for pointing me in the right direction.</sub>