# How can I prevent vim from trying to connect to an X server?

Tags: x11, vim, gui, vi

I'm starting vim in a bash session, within an SSH session. This session has X forwarding enabled, for reasons, but - I want vim to *not* try to connect to the X server (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/732689/34868)).

Other unsetting the `DISPLAY` environment variable - can I do something for vim itself, to prevent it from connecting to the X server (regardless of whether or not `DISPLAY` is defined)?

Answer (score 2):

"-X" will prevent vim from connecting to X server.

```bash
vim -X
```

Quoting from the man page:

```
-X          Don't connect to the X server.  Shortens startup time
            in a terminal, but the window title and clipboard will
            not be used.
```

If you want this to be for all times you run vim, then you can add an alias to your .bash_profile like this:

```bash
alias vim="/bin/vim -X"
```

Comment: ... but I would rather vim behave this way _without_ remembering the command-line argument, e.g. using `.vimrc` or something. ... oh, wait! It can be done apparently.